# How to make the bot join voice channels in all server the bot is?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, voice

```
+eval client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => { let targetGuild = client.guilds.cache.get(`${guild.id}`);
    
targetGuild.channels.cache.filter(ch => ch.type === 'voice').random().join()
  });
```

I tried this but it returned an error

Cannot read property join of undefined!!

Comment: I suspect your channel filter never matches so it produces an empty list. `ch.type` is supposed to be compared with values from the [`ChannelType`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ChannelType) enum.

Comment: @Ouroborus Depends, if OP is still using V12 `ch.type === 'voice'` will work. But, if OP updated to v13, voice type `voice` is invalid and returns false everytime, thus it needs to be `GUILD_VOICE`.

Comment: Also, voice is not supported in v13. They’ll have to use the `@discord.js/voice` package